# Children of a OneDrive DriveItem by RelativePath does not work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When I call below url from graph exlorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/folder2/children
```

I get below error:

```
"error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
```

But when I call same url without the /children  :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/folder2
```

Then it works and returns the information for folder2. Folder2 is under root directly and contains files and other folders.

Is this an issue in the graph api or is it something I am doing wrong? This is in OneDrive for Business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:{path}:` tells the API that you want to [address an item by its path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems) rather than it's ID. In your URI, you're missing the closing `:` which leaves the API attempting to find the path `/folder2/children` rather than the path `/folder2` and the API action `/children`.

Breaking this down to its components:

- API Address: `https://graph.microsoft.com`
- API Version: `/v1.0`
- Drive: `/me/drive/root`
- DriveItem Path: `:/folder2:`
- Request Action: `/children`

Put together, your URI should look like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/folder2:/children
```

Also note that if `folder2` contained a sub-folder named `folder3`, you can address that by path as well:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/folder2/folder3:/children
```